# Solaris 11.4, zfs_xcopy parameters

Tags: zfs, solaris-11

Can anybody explain new parameters appeared in oracle solaris 11.4?

```
zfs_write_throttle_xcopy_scale
zfs_xcopy_allowed_pct_over
zfs_xcopy_bloom_entries
zfs_xcopy_hard_limit_factor
zfs_xcopy_hard_limit_pct
zfs_xcopy_low_write_factor
zfs_xcopy_lower_bound_pct
zfs_xcopy_prefetch
zfs_xcopy_throttle_threshold
zfs_xcopy_upper_bound_pct
zfs_xdvnodeops
zfs_xdvnodeops_template
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the `xcopy` parameters are tunables for [ZFS version 38 and higher's "xcopy with encryption" feature](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E61017/gjxle.html).  Whatever "xcopy with encryption" may be, it's not described on [the ZFS Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS)